# How to make an "if" like structure in HTML

Tags: html

On my website, I want to add a form that takes your name and depending on the name, tells you what your role is. This is for when people have private roles and such.

How can I accomplish this in HTML without the use of JavaScript? If its not possible what might I need to do if I want the name "jack" to display "writer"?

Thank you.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: HTML is a markup language to describe structure. It doesn't really let you define behavior or process input.

Comment: I would use an HTML input box to use a JavaScript function on the fly to write an output... Or a dependency using a drop down with an already loaded set of names, depending on the name, have the other drop down display potential outputs.

Comment: But all of this would in fact need some type of front end tool such as JavaScript because HTML is static and JavaScript is not.

Comment: @FelixKling how about css3 and contains? I know it is almost like jQuery in some cases

Comment: @mplungjan: CSS is not HTML :P (but yeah, you can do cool stuff with CSS3)

Comment: I of course know - but the people who ask about "no javascript" are often worried that people will turn it off. I have not found a good example of text appearing depending on content

Answer (score 1):

In plain HTML it is not possible unless you use a sever process (which may be a good idea depending on the size of your list of roles)

In JavaScript something like this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/E7ejw/)

```
var roles = {
  "jack":"writer",
  "jill":"reader"
}
function matchRole(theField) {
  var role = roles[theField.value.toLowerCase()];
  document.getElementById("role").innerHTML=role?role:"";
}
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("username").onkeyup=function() { 
    matchRole(this);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not an interactive language. You will either need to use Javascript or a form and a server-side language such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using only HTML.  You need a client-side or server-side script (or a combination of the two) to process the form entry and update the page.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using pure HTML. HTML is only a markup language: it describes how the page will look, not how it will function.

If you want to have buttons and form that have an effect, you will need a scripting language somewhere in your stack. One option would be to use Javascript to listen to the button click and change the layout based on the entered value. Another option would be to use the `form`'s HTML attributes to direct the user to a server-side script—written in PHP, Python or pretty much any other language—that uses the value sent by the form to generate a new page with the information you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

HTML & CSS, as far as I'm concerned, are considered *[declarative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)*, therefore it is impossible to achieve what you want without a programming language like Javascript (client side) or PHP (server side).

Comment: Most projects certainly grow in time, and when they do, you don't want to start refactoring your code around a templating engine - you'd want to do that from the start. Why make it more difficult for your future self or reinvent something that has already been done before? Focus on the unique aspect of your application, not boiler plate code.

Comment: Don't stretch the argument.

Comment: To be honest, I believe that your animosity towards templating engines is not based on facts, but rather a stereotype, myth or just personal preference. Adding a little bit of abstraction to ease your passage through the vast wastelands of template-less PHP codebase is more than welcome, at least in my book.

Comment: There is no animosity - just pragmatism. OP asks a simple question and you roll out the big guns which are bound to a SPECIFIC server side language before even knowing if OP even has access to a server side process

Comment: That was a rather big assumption, I agree.

Comment: I've edited my answer to better reflect the ongoing discussion.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is short for HypterText Markup Language, and as a markup language it does not have conditional or looping constructs inherently. Instead, [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (or the ie only [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)) were developed to provide that capability on the client side. Originally, form based inputs were the only option for performing logic (e.g. server side logic).